# how to replace values in 2 dataframe columns based on multiple conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having columns in pandas dataframe which look like this:

| Positive | Neutral | Negative |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |

I want it to look like this:

| Positive | Neutral | Negative | Mixed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

First, I created column called mixed based on the fact that sentence is both positive and negative. Now, since I already have column "mixed", I do not need double information, so I would like to replace values in positive and negative columnwith 0 (only for mixed sentiment sentences). I've tried different variation of np.where but nothing seems to understand how to replace value in 2 columns based on condition from these 2 columns.
Any suggestions? Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do it in two steps - set the mixed column - then set the pos/neg columns to 0.

```
>>> df['Mixed'] = 0
>>> df
   Positive  Neutral  Negative  Mixed
0         1        0         1      0
1         0        1         0      0
>>> rows = (df.Positive == 1) & (df.Negative == 1)
>>> df.loc[rows, 'Mixed'] = 1
>>> df.loc[rows, ['Positive', 'Negative']] = 0
>>> df
   Positive  Neutral  Negative  Mixed
0         0        0         0      1
1         0        1         0      0
```

You can use
[`df.mask()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html#pandas-dataframe-mask) if you want to do it all together.

```
>>> df
   Positive  Neutral  Negative  Mixed
0         1        0         1      0
1         0        1         0      0
>>> rows = (df.Positive == 1) & (df.Negative == 1)
>>> df.mask(rows, [0, 0, 0, 1])
   Positive  Neutral  Negative  Mixed
0         0        0         0      1
1         0        1         0      0
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bit unclear from your question. I guess your question (if i am correct) is to change from this:

| Positive | Neutral | Negative |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |

to this (since you have a new column called "mixed"):

| Positive | Neutral | Negative | Mixed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

If this is the case, then the code should be (i make the table with 3 rows instead of 1 for easy to see):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Positive': [1, 1, 1], 'Neutral': [0, 0, 0], 'Negative': [1, 1, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
print(\n)
x = (df['Positive'])
x[1] = 0 
print(df)
```

As the result, in column "Positive", the second row, value is changed from "1" to "0".

With the different index, you can adjust the code by yourself at `x[i] = 0`. Similar code applied on "Negative" column.

Comment: I updated the post to show you what exactly I mean - your method can be used to single row. I have to do it for multiple rows, and as in an example - not every row is mixed sentiment

Comment: you can make the condition to define/change value of index `i` so it can be done in multiple rows. However, the answer from @Karl is better, hope it will solves your problem.